# Original node changes when inserting nodes into binary tree

Tags: c, insert, binary-tree

I'm trying to make a binary tree using a recursive insert function but my root node seems to keep changing(if it didn't, printf should always give the same output in the code below). Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
typedef struct Tnode{

    char name[30];
    int value;

    struct Tnode *left;
    struct Tnode *right;

} Tnode;


Tnode *insert(Tnode *node, char *name, int value){ 

    if(node==NULL){

        Tnode *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Tnode));

        sprintf(temp->name,"%s",name);
        temp->value = value;

        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;

        return temp;

    }

    else if(strcmp(name,node->name)<0)
    {
        node->left = insert(node->left, name, value);   
    }

    else if(strcmp(name,node->name)>0)
    {
        node->right = insert(node->right, name, value);
    }   
    else{
        printf("something went wrong\n");
    }   

}


int main(){

    Tnode *root = NULL;

    root = insert(root,"george",11);
    root = insert(root,"dick",12);
    printf("%s\n",root->name);  
    root = insert(root,"walter",13);
    root = insert(root,"harry",13);
    printf("%s\n",root->name);  
    root = insert(root,"zink",40);
    printf("%s\n",root->name);  


}
```

Comment: please show us the output

Comment: you always assign `root = insert(...)`, but after the first insert, this call doesn't return anything. you need to pass the return value through the recursive calls back to the initial call from main()

Comment: each of the above is on a newline

Comment: Pavel, could you provide some syntax? I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: just add `return node;` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so now we've figured it out together. your `insert()` is declared as

```
Tnode *insert(...)
```

so it allways needs to return a pointer to a Tnode, but there are cases in your if-clause that lead to an execution branch that doesn't return anything. I guess it's undefined what will be the return value.

Since insert() operates recursively by passing the call "if you're a leaf, put the value here and return yourself", you need to handle the case "and if you're not, do ... **and return ...**". So imagine you already have a large tree and you insert a value, the root passes the call down the binary structure until the correct position is found. The final call (where the recursion ends) will return a *Tnode to that leaf so that the previous call can correctly set `node->left = insert(...);`, but there are still "open" calls on the stack (since it's a recursion) that needs to get closed, i.e. the function terminates and every node writes something into `node->left` or `node->right`. If you don't return anything, there might be some arbitrary values that break your data structure and lead to undefined behavior.

So, the solution was just to add a `return node;` at the end so that the recursive calls can  be finalized by leaving the "passing" nodes between the root and the new leaf unchanged.

Comment: Thanks so much Pavel - everything is running smoothly now. A little new to recursion so this helped a lot!